# How can i prevent that scroll offset be bigger than view content (NestedScrollView and TabBarView)

Tags: scroll, dart, flutter, tabs, tabview

I'm using slivers to get a animated page with a header collapsable and a TabView body, but the offset of scroll is considering the fully page. What i need to do to get the right offset ? I'm putting an example about what happens.

I'm using flutter 1.2.1

```
    NestedScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            backgroundColor: greenColor.withOpacity(0.6),
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
              background: _buildHeader(context),
            ),
            expandedHeight: 300.0,
            bottom: _buildTabBar(),
          )
        ];
      },
      body: _buildTabView(context),
    )
```

I expect the offset stops when the header stops of being collapsed

[image: NestedScroll example]

Comment: you could remove withOpacity  : greenColor.withOpacity(0.6)

Comment: @diegoveloper i put the opacity just to show the problem, the contents is going to behind the app bar and needs to stop when the header stops to being collapsed, the right way is to go behind when the content of the page will be larger than the space, can you understand ? I'm sorry for english mistakes, i'm not fluently